# How do I design the interface for querying if an optional field is involved as part of querying

Tags: user-interface, usability

How do I design the interface for querying if an optional field is part of the record.

```
Record contains (name, foo_type, bar_type, value)
```

foo_type could be foo1, foo2
bar_type is either bar1, bar2 and is valid only for foo1, if foo2 is stored the value of bar_type is always null.

I would like to filter records which are by a certain bar_type say bar1 or bar2. But it won't make sense if foo(s) are selected (say fooX, fooY) which don't have a bar_type. In such cases the result set would be empty, if the user selects either bar1 or bar2.

How do I design a intuitive UI over here.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say with the examples being generic. If you're example maps onto your actual domain then I would just wrap up your two options into a single selection - since there are only three options:

- foo1 & bar1
- foo1 & bar2
- foo2

Other ways you can approach it is to incrementally reveal further options depending on the ones initially selected. For example I designed a contact form where one of the questions was "How do you want to be contacted?" If they selected "phone" we revealed a phone field. If they selected by post we revealed an address field. And so on.

Can you talk about your actual domain? That would help folk give a better answer.